# How to create a new Facebook application in C# as facebook has obslete the FBML for now

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, new-operator

As we well know that facebook has made heavy changes in their privacy policy. and as per now they have stooped supporting FBML.
So can any one please tell me what is the new  procedure and some code snippets to create an application in facebook with as.net, C#.

Answer (score 3):

The best advice is to read the [Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/). FBML has been replaced by [Social Plugs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) which run client side. They are pretty easy to use from anywhere to quickly enable integration and to pull Facebook features into your site.

I wrote an article [here](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2011/07/facebook-integration-via-hammock.html) which shows how to mix server-side C# logic and leverage `Social Plugins` for authentication.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the writing back.."The Code king" m confused in new setting in the app setting, is it will work fine for localhost as i'm developing application in c#. Actually i wanted to add invit friend functionality in my application. kindly refer some good links, and tell me am i able to send request to all the fb friends. thanks for writing me back..waiting for hear from you soon.

Comment: For testing on `localhost`, setup a test application in Facebook and set your callback address to `http://localhost`. The link to Facebook documentation should help, if you have a specific question create a new one :)